# Python Import Error : Unable to to import JWTBearerToken from authlib.oauth2.rfc7523

Tags: python, python-3.x, authlib

I am trying to use `JWTBearerToken` from `authlib.oauth2.rfc7523`.  However, I have encountered import error when trying to import `JWTBearerToken`:

**Create a virtual environment and install authlib**

```
$ pyenv virtualenv authlib
$ pyenv activate authlib
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip install authlib
```

**Start authlib and try to import `JWTBearerToken`**

```py
>>> from authlib.oauth2.rfc7523 import JWTBearerToken
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'JWTBearerToken' from 'authlib.oauth2.rfc7523' (/Users/simon/.pyenv/versions/authlib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/rfc7523/__init__.py)
>>>
```

**Try and import via validator module**

```py
>>> from authlib.oauth2.rfc7523.validator import JWTBearerToken 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authlib.oauth2.rfc7523.validator'
```

The source for the module is [here](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/oauth2/rfc7523/__init__.py).

What is the correct way to import JWTBearerToken or is this a bug with `authlib` library?

Comment: Downloading the source of that module and looking inside of the same file as the repository, then `'JWTBearerToken',` isn't there inside of the `__all__`  list. So, either there were minor changes in the published version on Pypi, or the included file was not the updated version.

Comment: Hi, thanks, appreciated :) Downloaded source from master branch and ```__all__ = [
    'JWTBearerGrant',
    'JWTBearerClientAssertion',
    'client_secret_jwt_sign',
    'private_key_jwt_sign',
    'ClientSecretJWT',
    'PrivateKeyJWT',

    'JWTBearerToken',
    'JWTBearerTokenGenerator',
    'JWTBearerTokenValidator',
]
``` Does the blank line after 'PrivateKeyJWT' make the remaining items in all list private?

Comment: Updated list to ensure link provided in question references master branch init py file for the module.